# Error when using MEFContrib with MVC3 on Mono

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, mono, mef

After managing to get Mono & Mod_Mono installed on my Centos 5 server, I have managed to get the server to activate my MVC3 site (which runs happily under IIS).

Unfortunately, when trying to run with Apache, I am getting an error:

Method not found: 'System.Web.Helpers.Chart.ExecuteChartAction'.
Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

This is peculiar to me as I have no reference in my code to the Chart Class at all. The exception also appears to be coming from Composition, and the stack trace includes various references to MefContrib.

I have experimented with having various different combinations of .dlls in my bin directory. This is its current contents which got me to this stage:

```
MyDll.dll            MefContrib.Web.Mvc.dll  System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
MyDll.pdb            System.Web.Helpers.dll  System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.xml
MyDll2.dll           System.Web.Helpers.xml  System.Web.WebPages.dll
MyDll2.pdb           System.Web.Mvc.dll      System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
HtmlAgilityPack.dll  System.Web.Mvc.xml      System.Web.WebPages.Razor.xml
HtmlAgilityPack.pdb  System.Web.Razor.dll    System.Web.WebPages.xml
HtmlAgilityPack.xml  System.Web.Razor.xml    WebActivator.dll
MefContrib.dll       System.Web.Routing.dll
```

Where MyDll & MyDll2 are project dlls that I have built that include various Exports & Imports of services for MEF to compose.

My best guess is that there is something in the MefContrib dlls that don't play nicely with Mono as, other than this, my project is an extremely simple MVC3 app.

Full Stack Trace:
    Server Error in '/' Application

```
Method not found: 'System.Web.Helpers.Chart.ExecuteChartAction'.

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

Server Error in '/' Application

Method not found: 'System.Web.Helpers.Chart.ExecuteChartAction'.

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Web.Helpers.Chart.ExecuteChartAction'.
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo.get_method_info (intptr,System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo&) <IL 0x00008, 0x0004c>
at System.Reflection.MonoMethodInfo.GetMethodInfo (intptr) [0x00000] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:63
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.GetPseudoCustomAttributes () [0x00002] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:295
at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetPseudoCustomAttributes (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider,System.Type) [0x0000d] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/corlib/System/MonoCustomAttrs.cs:68
at System.MonoCustomAttrs.IsDefined (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider,System.Type,bool) [0x00039] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/corlib/System/MonoCustomAttrs.cs:291
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.IsDefined (System.Type,bool) [0x00000] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:276
at Microsoft.Internal.AttributeServices.IsAttributeDefined<System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportAttribute> (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider,bool) <0x00036>
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModel.AttributedPartCreationInfo.IsExport (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider) [0x00000] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/AttributedModel/AttributedPartCreationInfo.cs:355
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModel.AttributedPartCreationInfo/<GetExportMembers>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x0017f] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/AttributedModel/AttributedPartCreationInfo.cs:302
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any<System.Reflection.MemberInfo> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Reflection.MemberInfo>) <0x0009e>
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModel.AttributedPartCreationInfo.HasExports () [0x00000] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/AttributedModel/AttributedPartCreationInfo.cs:106
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModel.AttributedPartCreationInfo.IsPartDiscoverable () [0x0003a] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/AttributedModel/AttributedPartCreationInfo.cs:95
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModel.AttributedModelDiscovery.CreatePartDefinitionIfDiscoverable (System.Type,System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ICompositionElement) [0x0000a] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/AttributedModel/AttributedModelDiscovery.cs:19
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.TypeCatalog.get_PartsInternal () [0x00051] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/TypeCatalog.cs:166
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.TypeCatalog.get_Parts () [0x00006] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/TypeCatalog.cs:123
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.get_Parts () [0x00000] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/AssemblyCatalog.cs:137
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartCatalog) <IL 0x00001, 0x00013>
at System.Linq.Enumerable/<CreateSelectManyIterator>c__Iterator29`2<System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartCatalog, System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartDefinition>.MoveNext () <0x00114>
at System.Linq.Enumerable/<CreateSelectManyIterator>c__Iterator29`2<System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartCatalog, System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartDefinition>.MoveNext () <0x00206>
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartDefinition>.AddEnumerable (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartDefinition>) <0x0008a>
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartDefinition>..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartDefinition>) <0x0008b>
at MefContrib.Hosting.Interception.InterceptingCatalog.GetParts () <IL 0x00033, 0x0009b>
at MefContrib.Hosting.Interception.InterceptingCatalog.get_Parts () <IL 0x00001, 0x0000f>
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePartCatalog.GetExports (System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportDefinition) [0x00017] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Primitives/ComposablePartCatalog.cs:88
at MefContrib.Hosting.Interception.InterceptingCatalog.GetExports (System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportDefinition) <IL 0x00010, 0x00033>
at MefContrib.Hosting.Filter.FilteringCatalog.GetExports (System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportDefinition) <IL 0x00007, 0x00021>
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportsCore (System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportDefinition,System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AtomicComposition) [0x00040] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/CatalogExportProvider.cs:279
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore (System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportDefinition,System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AtomicComposition,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export>&) [0x00006] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/ExportProvider.cs:208
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports (System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportDefinition,System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AtomicComposition) [0x0000b] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/ExportProvider.cs:102
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateExportProvider.GetExportsCore (System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportDefinition,System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AtomicComposition) [0x00030] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/AggregateExportProvider.cs:157
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore (System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportDefinition,System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AtomicComposition,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export>&) [0x00006] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/ExportProvider.cs:208
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExports (System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportDefinition,System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AtomicComposition,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export>&) [0x0000e] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/ExportProvider.cs:145
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.GetExportsCore (System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportDefinition,System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AtomicComposition) [0x00008] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/CompositionContainer.cs:396
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore (System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportDefinition,System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AtomicComposition,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export>&) [0x00006] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/ExportProvider.cs:208
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports (System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportDefinition,System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AtomicComposition) [0x0000b] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/ExportProvider.cs:102
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportsCore (System.Type,System.Type,string,System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportCardinality) [0x0006b] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/ExportProvider.GetExportOverrides.cs:799
at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports (System.Type,System.Type,string) [0x00000] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.ComponentModel.Composition/src/ComponentModel/System/ComponentModel/Composition/Hosting/ExportProvider.GetExportOverrides.cs:267
at MefContrib.Web.Mvc.CompositionDependencyResolver.GetService (System.Type) <IL 0x00009, 0x0002b>
at System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolverExtensions.GetService<System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory> (System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver) <0x0002d>
at System.Web.Mvc.SingleServiceResolver`1<System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory>.get_Current () <0x00097>
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBuilder.GetControllerFactory () <IL 0x00006, 0x00021>
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetSessionStateBehavior (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext) <IL 0x00024, 0x00097>
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext) <IL 0x00008, 0x0002c>
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext) <IL 0x00002, 0x00015>
at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache (System.Web.HttpContextBase) [0x00054] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.Web.Routing/System.Web.Routing/UrlRoutingModule.cs:127
at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache (object,System.EventArgs) [0x00007] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.Web.Routing/System.Web.Routing/UrlRoutingModule.cs:87
at System.Web.HttpApplication/<RunHooks>c__Iterator5.MoveNext () [0x001aa] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1050
at System.Web.HttpApplication/<Pipeline>c__Iterator6.MoveNext () [0x006d3] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1259
at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/mono-2.10.2/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:932
Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.2 (tarball Mon Apr 18 19:06:50 UTC 2011); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This other question led me to an answer to this question:
[missingmethodexception-w-mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442812/missingmethodexception-w-mono)

As it turns out, MefContrib is set up to use a DirectoryCatalog by default and this just does not work with Mono (due to it trying to find Exports in dlls that have none - something that is fine in Windows).

If you replace the MvcApplicationRegistry in the Start() method for your application with your own custom one that just looks at your dlls (and doesn't scan the whole bin) then everything is happy.

Start() method:

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
            new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass))),
            new ConventionCatalog(new MyMvcApplicationRegistry()));
```

MvcApplicationRegistry:

```
public class MyMvcApplicationRegistry : PartRegistry
      {
        public MyMvcApplicationRegistry()
        {
            Scan(x => x.Assembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

            Part()
                .ForTypesAssignableFrom<IController>()
                .MakeNonShared()
                .AddMetadata(new PartCreationScopeAttribute(PartCreationScope.Default))
                .ExportAs<IController>()
                .Export()
                .Imports(x =>
                {
                    x.Import().Members(
                        m => new[] { m.GetConstructors().FirstOrDefault(c => c.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ImportingConstructorAttribute), false).Length > 0) ?? m.GetGreediestConstructor() });
                    x.Import().Members(
                        m => m.GetMembers().Where(mbr => mbr.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ImportAttribute), false).Length > 0).ToArray());
                });
        }
      }
```